# What is each group's permissions, and what is the "ranking" of each group (most privileged to least)?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, freebsd, group

I'm asking about who inherits permissions from who, along with any additional permissions for the group as well?

For example: "nogroup - no permissions,...(Insert other groups here)..., wheel - inherits from nogroup, (Insert other groups here),...(any "higher up" groups continue on).

Comment: you are confusing groups with privilege elevation. Groups do not inherit right from one another. Users **obtain** rights of the group that they are a member of and these rights are are generally for file and folder access. I think you have something else on your mind. But unless you can clearly state "rights for what" nobody can help you. Are you interested in sudo rights or something similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ranking or inheritance between groups. All groups are on an equal footing (or to be more precise, mathematically speaking, the privileges of groups are incomparable).

Groups confer privileges indirectly. This happens mainly through file permissions (which make members of a certain group able to access a file, or more rarely unable to access a file). This also happens when programs check group memberships, for example via `%group` user specifications in the sudo configuration.

Comment: So, being part of a group will allow you to get those specific permissions (ex: being part of ftp allows you to connect via ftp, sshd group - you can ssh into your box or whatever)? What about the difference between admin and wheel?

Comment: Group names are not standardized, but generally, you don't need to be a member of a group to use SSH or FTP. The `sshd` group is normally used for internal purposes by the SSH server. I think the `ftp` group is usually used for anonymous FTP. Ubuntu has a group called `admin` whose users are allowed to become root via `sudo`. The `wheel` group has its own diverse history; there are systems where `su` checks (user is in `wheel` OR knows the root password), systems where it checks (user is in `wheel` AND knows the root password) and systems (e.g. most Linux distros) where `wheel` has no meaning.